# Format textbox to take an IP Address on MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, textbox

I'm currently tidying up my C# MVC4 project with validation methods etc, majority is fine except for the IP address textboxes. Here admin add in the IP address of the workstations. I dont know how to format the textbox into the """"".""."".""" spaces. Any ideas?

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AssignedIP)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AssignedIP)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AssignedIP)
    </div>
```

model

```
      [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    [Display(Name = "Location Name")]
    public string LocationName { get; set; }

    public string AssignedIP { get; set; }
```

Comment: maybe you can try some jquery plugins, if it's option: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: and additionally a regular expression validation attribute on the server side: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want masked input in mvc I would suggest using jquery lib for that and creating extension method for your AssignedIP.

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-joshbush.googlecode.com/files/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.1.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#AssignedIP").mask("999.999.999.999");
        });
    </script>
```

Or if you just need validation then you can use regex for that:

```
^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$
```

it match the IPv4 addresses.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$")]
public string AssignedIP { get; set; }
```

in your ViewModel

Comment: Brillant @freshbm, thank you! i was thinking just of the regular expression but the mask helps as well, thanks!